# How do I define an environment variable/macro in a VC++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, environment-variables

I'm trying to build [FTGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/files/FTGL%20Source/) in Visual C++ 2008.  According to the documentation, I need to define a macro called `$(FREETYPE)` containing the path to the FreeType library code, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how that's done.

I've been all over the project options and the Visual C++ options, and I can't find the place to define this macro anywhere.  When I look for help online, all I find is stuff talking about how to define an environment variable in the debugger (not helpful when I'm trying to compile) or other pages saying to define it as a literal environment variable in the Control Panel, which is kind of ridiculous.  It smacks of [using global state to manage a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx).

I'm completely lost here.  I'm used to using Delphi, where doing this is trivial, and I can't believe that no mechanism for setting this macro exists anywhere in the Visual Studio IDE, so I figure I must be overlooking something.  Does anyone know the right place to define it so things will compile right?

Answer (score 0):

Well if nothing else works just define it in windows

Computer / Properties / Advanced System settings / Environment Variables

define `FREETYPE=` to whatever you want to set it then restart visual studio for it to take effect.